# Contractible chain complex defined as a direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra over a field $F$. Consider a chain complex $(X,\delta)$ if $\mathcal{A}$-modules. Denote $S_n(X) = X_{n-1} \oplus X_n$ and $D: F_n(X) \rightarrow F_{n-1}(X)$, defined as $D_n(x,y)=(-\delta_{n-1}(x),x+\delta_n(y))$. Can you please suggest, how to show that obtained in such a way chain complex is contractible? I am also trying to show that there exists an exact sequence
$$
  0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow F(X) \rightarrow X[1] \rightarrow 0.
$$
Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that $F(X)=\operatorname{cone}(\operatorname{id}^X)$. In which case the exact sequence is obvious (you can find this in Weibel or must any standard homological algebra text), that is, the first map is $x\mapsto (0,x)$ and the second map is $(x,y)\mapsto -x$. Also, since $\operatorname{id}^X$ is an isomorphism it's evidently a homotopy equivalence and hence, $\operatorname{cone}(\operatorname{id}^X)$ is contractible.

Alternatively, I think the homotopy is easy enough. That is, let $h_n: X_{n-1}\oplus X_n\to X_n\oplus X_{n+1}$ be $(x,y)\mapsto (y,0)$. Now observe that $$D h(x,y)+hD(x,y)=D(y,0)+h(-\delta(x),x+\delta(y))=(-\delta(y), y)+(x+\delta(y),0)=(x,y)$$